# What is the original order of found contours in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

If I acquire the contour lines of an image with the following:

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

what is the original "order" of the `contours` object list? Position (to-down/left-right), contour length, contour area, or anything else?

Comment: You could check that yourself by `drawContours` right?. If not, you might want to look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)